# SQL Nested Select - Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, nested

(I'm an Access/SQL beginner so please bear with me!) I have 3 tables - 1 with Regions and the Offices that fall under each, and 2 with monthly sales (Jan-Jun given in monthly totals) for each Office. I need to generate a report that shows Region, Office and the average Sales/day broken down by month. So I need 8 columns - Region, Office, and 6 Month columns. So far I have been able to union the two sales tables, join that with the Regions table, and split out the monthly sales per office for January (not per day, haven't been able to divide the total - but I'll figure that out later). My problem is now I'm stuck, I've tried to mirror the column for February off of Jan in Access's design view but the SQL that it writes is combining with Jan (sum if month = jan AND feb) which of course returns nothing when I run it. I know I need to write nested selects for the remaining months, but I can't find any examples that are comparable to what I need to accomplish. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Regions.Region, [SalesReg Union].Office, [SalesReg Union].Sales AS Jan
FROM Regions INNER JOIN [SalesReg Union] ON Regions.Office = [SalesReg Union].Office
GROUP BY Regions.Region, [SalesReg Union].Office, [SalesReg Union].Sales
HAVING ((([SalesReg Union].Sales)=(Sum(IIf([Month]='Jan',[Sales],0)))));
```

I'm stumped as to how to nest selects for the remaining months, any guidance would be appreciated!!

Comment: I might suggest using a "Nested query" for lack of a better term. In your "From" statement you can define a new table. For example, you might have `SELECT Table1.ID, sum(Jan.sales) FROM Table1 inner join (SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Sales FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Month = 'January') Jan on Table1.ID = Jan.ID GROUP BY Table1.ID` You would have to create a new table for each month, but this should work. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using MS Access' unique [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) (an available query type under the Query design ribbon) which pivots distinct values of one column as many columns, aggregated across specified values. In the query design, you can specify the following three components:

1. **ROW HEADING** (the groupby columns, *can be multiple fields*) (i.e., Region, Sales Office)
2. **COLUMN HEADING** (the pivot column which renders in `PIVOT` clause, can *only be one field*) (i.e., Sales month)
3. **VALUE** (the aggregated numeric column used in `TRANSFORM` clause, *can only be one field*) (i.e,. Sales)

Below is the SQL output which as you can see uses an aggregate query within it:

```
TRANSFORM Avg([SalesReg Union].Sales) AS AvgSales
SELECT Regions.Region, [SalesReg Union].Office
FROM Regions INNER JOIN [SalesReg Union] ON Regions.Office = [SalesReg Union].Office
GROUP BY Regions.Region, [SalesReg Union].Office
PIVOT ([SalesReg Union].[Month]);
```

To use the crosstab query as recordsource in reports, you will need to fully specify the values of pivot columns using the `IN()` clause in `PIVOT()` (so report knows in advance its own structure):

```
PIVOT ([SalesReg Union].[Month]) IN ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun')
```

Furthermore, you can even subset using this `IN()` clause. Below shows only first three months.

```
PIVOT ([SalesReg Union].[Month]) IN ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar')
```

At times, this may be necessary as the maximum number of columns in table/query is 255 which can easily be reached in a crosstab depending on column header field. Finally, please note this query is not portable to other RDMS's. It is uniquely an MS Access SQL query type.

Comment: Now I also need to make an input form that's able to run the query based on a selected date range. I changed the PIVOT to [SalesReg Union].Start, which works the same as Month (1/1/2015 instead of 'Jan'), but I can't figure out how to work in the End date so that the form will work correctly. Do you have any ideas? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Simply add a `WHERE` clause for date range. No need to adjust `PIVOT()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Regions.Region, [SalesReg Union].Office, Sum(Jan.Sales) as 'Jan', Sum(Feb.Sales) as 'Feb', Sum(Mar.Sales) as 'Mar', Sum(Apr.Sales) as 'Apr', Sum(May.Sales) as 'May', Sum(Jun.Sales) as 'Jun'
FROM Regions 
INNER JOIN [SalesReg Union] ON Regions.Office = [SalesReg Union].Office
INNER JOIN (Select SR.Office, SR.Sales FROM [SalesReg Union] SR WHERE SR.Month = 'Jan') Jan on Jan.Office = Regions.Office
INNER JOIN (Select SR.Office, SR.Sales FROM [SalesReg Union] SR WHERE SR.Month = 'Feb') Feb on Feb.Office = Regions.Office
INNER JOIN (Select SR.Office, SR.Sales FROM [SalesReg Union] SR WHERE SR.Month = 'Mar') Mar on Mar.Office = Regions.Office
INNER JOIN (Select SR.Office, SR.Sales FROM [SalesReg Union] SR WHERE SR.Month = 'Apr') Apr on Apr.Office = Regions.Office
INNER JOIN (Select SR.Office, SR.Sales FROM [SalesReg Union] SR WHERE SR.Month = 'May') May on May.Office = Regions.Office
INNER JOIN (Select SR.Office, SR.Sales FROM [SalesReg Union] SR WHERE SR.Month = 'Jun') Jun on Jun.Office = Regions.Office
GROUP BY Regions.Region, [SalesReg Union].Office
```

This query is certainly not the prettiest query, but it will probably be functional and get you want you need.